Why am I unable to activate hotspot on Windows 11?
For a few days now I can't activate hotspot on my PC from the settings or the taskbar but I can use commands (netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=ssid key=key and netsh wlan start hostednetwork), nothing special happened since this problem came.
The WiFi card I'm using is the Realtek RTL8192EE Wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-E NIC. It's not very important but I would like to know why this is happening and how to fix it.
Here are all the things I've tried to fix that, but without any results:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/unable-to-activate-hotspot/bb870698-bff0-420c-b5eb-d44535b47398


What do you mean "I can using commands? What commands work for you? Also, try to do a network reset: Select Start > Settings > Network & internet > Advanced network settings > Network reset

Can you provide information about the hardware you are using? And, as others are asking, specifically what you are trying to do? Do you have a MiFi device that your computer won't connect to, or are you trying to use your computer to create a hotspot? What happened since you started having this problem?

@1NN I already tried to do a network reset but it didn't lead to anything .                               I use netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=ssid key=key then netsh wlan start hostednetwork

@CaturdaySaint Sorry for the lack of information, I try to setup a hotspot from my pc using taskbar tools.  My WiFi card is a  Realtek RTL8192EE Wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-E NIC and nothing special happened.

Please integrate the elements of your last two comments into your question by clicking on "edit" and adding the text. Relevant information must be in the question, not in comments. Thank you.
